# Enclose html element in another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bit of a problem and I'm not sure if it's possible with js.
Lets say I have a `p` Element.

```
<p class="test> text text text </p>
```

Is it possible that jquery would be able to turn the statement above into this.

```
<div class="new_created">
<p class="test> text text text </p>
</div>
```

All on run-time and assuming I can't manually modify it myself. 
Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) wrap elements with another element

```
$('.test').wrap('<div class="new_created"/>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qtnzh/)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your HTML looks like this

```
<div>
    <p class="test">text text text</p>
</div>
```

Then, you can do

```
$('.test').wrap($('<div class="new_created">'));
```

Comment: `$('.test').wrap($('<div class="new_created">'));` is an unnecessary overhead. Use a string representation instead but.. ya, that's already answered by Arun